# Как правильно связать Eloquent во Vue Laravel, чтобы достать в компоненте поле

Tags: laravel, vue.js, eloquent

подскажите как правильно достать в компоненте поле из связанной таблицы?

У меня есть контроллер ProductController - в котором функция index() - отображает все товары

```
public function index()
{
    $product = Product::latest()->paginate(10);
    $product->load('categories');
    return response()->json($product);
}
```

Есть модель Product - в которой связь

```
public function categories(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

И есть Component - в который передаются данные

```
data() {
        return {
            products: {},
            form: new Form({
                id : '',
                title : '',
                image : '',
                category_id : '',
                price : '',
                description : '',
            })
        }
    },
methods: {
loadProducts(){
            axios.get('api/products')
                .then(({ data }) => (this.products = data.data ));

        },
}
```

И на выходе я перебираю объект - products

```
<tr v-for="product in products" :key="product.id">
                            <td>{{product.id}}</td>
                            <td>{{product.title | upText}}</td>
                            <td>{{product.price}}</td>
                            <td>{{product.category_id}}</td>
                            <td>{{product.description}}</td>
                            <td>{{product.image}}</td>
                            <td>{{product.created_at | myDate}}</td>
                            <td><span class="tag tag-success">
                                <a href="#" v-on:click="editModal(product)"><i class="fa fa-pen">Edit</i></a>
                            </span></td>
                            <td><span class="tag tag-success">
                                <a href="#" v-on:click="deleteProduct(product.id)"><i class="fa fa-trash">Delete</i></a>
                            </span></td>
                        </tr>
```

Как мне через связь categories - получать Имя категории, вместо - {{product.category_id}}

И очень странно, что я когда приходит объект - у меня пустые categories - null?

```
categories: null
```

category_id: 45
created_at: "2021-03-17T07:18:58.000000Z"
description: "Name"
id: 1
image: null
price: "500"
slug: "slug"
title: "Name"
updated_at: "2021-03-17T07:18:58.000000Z"

Answer (score 0):

Додумался, не знаю почему - но проблема была со связями ! Оказывается, нужно точно указать внешний ключ и внутренний.

```
public function categories(){
return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id', 'id');
```

}

Ппц, на Blade'ах такого делать не нужно...  Там автоматом подтягивалось)